# A question about nonparametric (kernel function) estimation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, taylor-expansion, statistical-inference, infinitesimals

Suppose $X_1,\cdots,X_n\overset{iid}\sim F$, the $q$th quantile $\theta=F^{-1}(q)$. Let $K$ denote an $r$th order kernel. That is for some integer $r\ge2$ and constant $C\neq0$, $K$ satisfies
$$$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int u^jK(u)du=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
1,  &   \quad\textrm{if} \quad j=0, \\
0,  &   \quad\textrm{if} \quad 1\le j\le r-1,\\
C, &   \quad\textrm{if} \quad j=r.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let
$$w_i=w_i(\theta)=\int_{-\infty}^\theta\frac1hK(\frac{y-X_i}h)dy-q$$
and
$$\bar w_2=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nw_i^2$$
Show that $$E(\bar w_2)=q(1-q)+o(1).$$

---

$$E(\bar w_2)=Ew_i^2=E(\int_{-\infty}^\theta\frac1hK(\frac{y-X_i}h)dy)^2-2q\cdot E(\int_{-\infty}^\theta\frac1hK(\frac{y-X_i}h)dy)+q^2$$

By Fubini's theorem and Taylor expansion, I can get the second term equals to
$$-2q(q+o(1))=-2q^2+o(1)$$

My question is how to deal with the first term?

This question comes from the paper

*[Smoothed Empirical Likelihood Confidence Intervals for Quantiles](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2242193?Search=yes&resultItemClick=true&searchText=Smoothed&searchText=Empirical&searchText=Likelihood&searchText=Confidence&searchText=Intervals&searchText=for&searchText=Quantiles&searchUri=%2Faction%2FdoBasicSearch%3Facc%3Don%26amp%3BQuery%3DSmoothed%2BEmpirical%2BLikelihood%2BConfidence%2BIntervals%2Bfor%2BQuantiles%26amp%3Bfc%3Doff%26amp%3Bwc%3Don%26amp%3Bgroup%3Dnone&refreqid=search%3A207044e8828653868d7c6e8c6b782f97&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)*

by Song Xi Chen and Peter Hall on page 1175.